# Using Active Directory Login Dialog in asp.net MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, active-directory

I need for my **ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application** to make use of the same **login dialog of Active Directory** to restrict some actions of a controller, like only being able to save a sign entry in DB if the user authenticate himself like a user of a Role (the current logged user in AD may not be that user, in fact the access is public, the Web Application works inside a intranet)

I really need to use the original login dialog of AD, I know that I can do this by others ways like using *System.DirectoryServices* or *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement*, I have read about **ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider**. Can it be the solution to my problem? There is any solution to this in my current environment?

I need any clue or example of what may I do, I have been looking for it in Google for ages...

Sorry about my English and thanks very much in advance.